# Outlook group by flag status

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to be able to pin mails to the top of my inbox in outlook (this used to be possible, but there is no longer a pin option) so I resorted to using the "Followup Flag" as a pin by making my inbox grouped by Flag stutus. But this results in something very annoying: A "Completed Section" above the ordinary inbox (ordinary inbox is "Unflagged" and contains 99% of the mails I receive). I do not want to have a "completed" group, just want some way to rig outlook so that some mails appear on top in a way I can unpin by the click of a button.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to achieve - a way to pin emails to the top of my inbox using a better technique? I want it to be very very simplistic, like the "pin" feature that seems to have been removed.

[image]

[image]

And this is what my outlook looks like, there is no longer a pin option:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the type of your account(Exchange/POP/IMAP)?

If it's ***an Exchange or a POP account***, as I know, we can easily flag the emails (right the email>Follow Up>No Date) you need to pin on the top of Inbox, and then select Filter: All Mail and Arranged by: Flag Due Date. Then the emails flagged will be placed on the top of Inbox.

[image]

[image]

If it's ***an IMAP account***, it's suggested that you could achieve pinning the emails on the top of Inbox by flagging messages and changing the view. For specific steps, please refer to:

1.Flag the emails you want to pin on the top of Inbox;

[image]

2.Turn off the reading pane;

[image]

3.Click the flag icon to sort by the flag column;

[image]

4.Turn on the reading pane and save this view and rename it as Pin(View>Change View>Save Current view As a New View… );

[image]

In this way, the marked message will be placed on the top of Inbox, and then when you continue to mark the message later, it will be placed on the top.

Hope the above help!

Comment: The problem is what happens when I unflag it. I dont want unflagged mails to be a special category of "completed flag". I want unflagging to be as if I had never flagged them.

Comment: Through the two methods I mentioned above, the emails that becomes completed after you unflag will remain at the top. It is these emails with flag and completed status that can remain at the top, so once the flag is cleared, they will not continue to be at the top. I'm afraid only by keeping these flags can we keep them on the top.

Comment: If you use an Exchange or a POP account, of course you can also use the category to mark the emails you want to top, and then use the Arraged by: category to top these emails. In this way you don't need to consider the trouble caused by the change of flags.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: The solution seems too involved. I have found that right click->follow up->clear flag prevents the email from being categories as "completed".